# Как выделить содержимое div и скопировать содержимое в буфер обмена?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, clipboard

Как с помощью jQuery по клику выделить содержимое div?

И второй вопрос: как при этом скопировать содержимое в буфер обмена?

Comment: Плагин jquery использую чще всего, clipboard называется

Comment: Похоже, придётся подменять div чем-то. Например, `input` с `type='text'`. Выделение фрагмента страницы в браузере - это внешняя операция, доступная пользователю страницы, с помощью js api можно управлять только выделением текстовых полей.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Код взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/1548895)

```js
function selectText(elementId) {
    var doc = document,
        text = doc.getElementById(elementId),
        range,
        selection;
        
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}

$("#text").click(function() {
    selectText(this.id);
    document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  This is text
  <span>this is another text</span>
</div>
```